# TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method (Book example not working)

Tags: python, pygame

Recently I picked up a book given to me by my work experience guy to learn Pygame. The problem is it's from 2007 and the book uses python 2.4 and Pygame 1.7.1 so I've encountered some issues I've been able to resolve myself but since I'm onto the chapter with Pygame now, it's completely new territory for me with slightly more complex python coding than I am used to. My previous experience is what I did in school and what I've done with my work experience guy so I'm still fairly new to programming.

The error I have encountered is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/python_repository/Pygame_projects_book/Message_Queue.py", line 17, in <module>
    event_text = event_text[-SCREEN_SIZE[1] / font_height:]
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

And here's the code that is creating the problem:

```
event = pygame.event.wait()
    event_text.append(str(event))
    event_text = event_text[-SCREEN_SIZE[1] / font_height:]
```

And for simplicity here's the whole listing from the book:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from sys import exit

pygame.init()
SCREEN_SIZE = (640, 480)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE, 0, 32)

font = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 16);
font_height = font.get_linesize()
event_text = []

while True:

    event = pygame.event.wait()
    event_text.append(str(event))
    event_text = event_text[-SCREEN_SIZE[1] / font_height:]

    if event.type == QUIT:
        exit()

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

    y = SCREEN_SIZE[1] - font_height
    for text in reversed(event_text):
        screen.blit(font.render(text, True, (0, 0, 0)), (0, y))
        y -= font_height

    pygame.display.update()
```

Since I'm still learning I'm not sure how to go about this error. Any help appreciated with a possible explanation what was causing the issue so I can learn from it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the line

```
event_text = event_text[-SCREEN_SIZE[1] / font_height:]
```

with

```
event_text = event_text[-SCREEN_SIZE[1] // font_height:]
```

to use [floor division](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/), ensuring that the division returns an integer instead of a float.

Comment: Didn't expect the answer to be so easy haha thank you works perfectly!